# git - ftp error while pushing files to production server

Tags: git, ftp, git-ftp

I am getting following error when I try to push my files to my production server using git ftp.

This is the error I get without the -v option

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git-ftp: line 408: /bin/curl: Bad file number
fatal: Could not upload files., exiting...
```

This is the detailed error generated using -v option

```
Wed Apr  9 15:00:04 IST 2014: Uploading ...
      0 [main] bash 5880 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.sta
ckdump
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git-ftp: line 400:  5880 Segmentation fault
(core dumped) curl "${CURL_ARGS[@]}"
Wed Apr  9 15:00:08 IST 2014: fatal: Could not upload files., exiting...
```

I am pushing these changes for the first time and I am using `git ftp init` command.

I have checked and the whole configuration is correct. In fact if I try to push a small number of files it works. But when I try to upload my library folder which is around 45 MB in size I get the above error.

Can any one please help with this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you ever find any solution? thanks.

Comment: @ErdemEce I have posted the solutions as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that git ftp has a bug and it won't work with a larger number of files.

So I did following to remove the error.

I am using Zend Framework. I uploaded my library/Zend folder manually to server and then ignored it using .git-ftp-ignore. This reduce the number of files that git ftp has to handle and now it works fine.

This solution worked for me because I rarely change library/Zend folder.

I have reported this bug

[git ftp bug](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/88)

Hope this helps others.